# Using np.select(), with a single-valued custom function as input

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have the following example code:

```
data = ['05/21/2021','05/21/2022','05/21/2023']    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['register_date'])
df['register_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['register_date']).dt.year
df['study_year'] = 2022
```

Here, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| register_date | register_year | study_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/21/2021 | 2021 | 2022 |
| 05/21/2022 | 2022 | 2022 |
| 05/21/2023 | 2023 | 2022 |

The goal is to create another column named "duration_start" where it is `1` if `register_year < study_year`, `0` if `register_year > study_year`, and the proportion of the year between year end of register_year and the register date if `register_year == study_year`.

I created the following conditions to be used with np.select()

```
register_year_lt_study_year = df['register_year'] < df['study_year']
register_year_gt_study_year = df['Register_year'] > df['Study_year']
```

And a function that calculates the proportion of the year from year end:

```
def proportion_to_year_end(date):
    start = pd.to_datetime(date)
    year_end = pd.to_datetime('12/31/' + str(start.year))
    return (year_end - start).days/365
```

However, I'm not sure how I should fill in the `??`, since proportion_to_year_end() is a single-valued function taking in a string, but np.select() accepts a column of the same length.

`df['duration_start'] = np.select([register_year_lt_study_year, register_year_gt_study_year], [1, 0], ??)`

I thought about using the `apply()` function, to perhaps generate another column and then drop it, but that would entail more logic to take care of the 0 and 1 first, then on top of that, apply proportion_to_year_end, then drop the temporary column.

Alternatively, I thought about changing proportion_to_year_end() to take in two columns, but I'm not sure how to write it without for-loops, which is something we should avoid.

I wonder if there are better ways to do these type of problems where there is an apparent dimension mismatch between a single-valued function and columns in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) indicates that the default must be a value, so I don't think you can apply your function there.

One thing you could do is partially fill the array with 1s and 0s, give a specific value to the rest of the array (where `register_year == study_year`) like nan or -1 and fill that section thanks to a mask. For example:

```
df['duration_start'] = np.select([register_year_lt_study_year, register_year_gt_study_year],
                                 [1, 0],
                                 np.nan)

mask = df['register_year'] == df['study_year']
df['duration_start'][mask] = np.vectorize(proportion_to_year_end)(df['study_year'][mask])
```

I had to use `vectorize` here, but if you change `proportion_to_year_end` to support an array of datetimes we can remove it.